# How to check which disk is mounted where? How to mount all spare disks?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive, raid, fdisk

Doing a `df -h`:

```
alvas@mt:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       3.5T  2.7T  597G  83% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             63G   12K   63G   1% /dev
tmpfs            13G  1.8M   13G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             63G   72K   63G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   20K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sdd5       1.8T 1005G  718G  59% /media/2tb
/dev/sdd1       1.9T  1.2T  531G  70% /media/2moretb
/dev/sde1       1.9T  214G  1.7T  12% /media/shiny
```

And then a `sudo fdisk -l`:

```
alvas@mt:~$ sudo fdisk -l

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 4000.2 GB, 4000225165312 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486333 cylinders, total 7812939776 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdc'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdc: 4000.2 GB, 4000225165312 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486333 cylinders, total 7812939776 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT

Disk /dev/sdd: 4000.2 GB, 4000225165312 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486333 cylinders, total 7812939776 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0003bd79

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1      3865466880  7812939775  1973736448   83  Linux
/dev/sdd2          501758  3865466879  1932482561    5  Extended
/dev/sdd5          503808  3865466879  1932481536   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 4000.2 GB, 4000225165312 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486333 cylinders, total 7812939776 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT

Disk /dev/sde: 2000.4 GB, 2000365289472 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243197 cylinders, total 3906963456 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2ae33383

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sde1            2048  3906963455  1953480704    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
alvas@mt:~$ 
alvas@mt:~$ df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2       3.5T  2.7T  597G  83% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev             63G   12K   63G   1% /dev
tmpfs            13G  1.8M   13G   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none             63G   72K   63G   1% /run/shm
none            100M   20K  100M   1% /run/user
/dev/sdd5       1.8T 1005G  718G  59% /media/2tb
/dev/sdd1       1.9T  1.2T  531G  70% /media/2moretb
/dev/sde1       1.9T  214G  1.7T  12% /media/shiny
alvas@mt:~$ sudo fdisk -l

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sda'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sda: 4000.2 GB, 4000225165312 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486333 cylinders, total 7812939776 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdc'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdc: 4000.2 GB, 4000225165312 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486333 cylinders, total 7812939776 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT

Disk /dev/sdd: 4000.2 GB, 4000225165312 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486333 cylinders, total 7812939776 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x0003bd79

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1      3865466880  7812939775  1973736448   83  Linux
/dev/sdd2          501758  3865466879  1932482561    5  Extended
/dev/sdd5          503808  3865466879  1932481536   83  Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order

WARNING: GPT (GUID Partition Table) detected on '/dev/sdb'! The util fdisk doesn't support GPT. Use GNU Parted.


Disk /dev/sdb: 4000.2 GB, 4000225165312 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 486333 cylinders, total 7812939776 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1               1  4294967295  2147483647+  ee  GPT

Disk /dev/sde: 2000.4 GB, 2000365289472 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243197 cylinders, total 3906963456 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x2ae33383

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sde1            2048  3906963455  1953480704    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

**How do I check whether my `sdb` and `sdc` drives is mounted? And if they are, where are they mounted?**

**What is `GPT (GUID Partition Table)`? **

**How do I check which disk is used and which disk is still a clean slate**

**How can I mount all spare unused drives into a single directory?**

**If not a single directory into separate directories in `/media/`?**

---

It's strange because `fdisk` showed 5 physical disks but `mount` can only find 2:

```
gillin@mt:~$ mount /dev/sda1
mount: can't find /dev/sda1 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
gillin@mt:~$ mount /dev/sdb1
mount: can't find /dev/sdb1 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
gillin@mt:~$ mount /dev/sdc1
mount: can't find /dev/sdc1 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab
gillin@mt:~$ mount /dev/sdd1
mount: according to mtab, /dev/sdd1 is already mounted on /media/2moretb
mount failed
gillin@mt:~$ mount /dev/sde1
mount: according to mtab, /dev/sde1 is already mounted on /media/shiny
mount failed
```

---

Using gparted, I've found `sdb` and sdc` but they're unformatted and they looked unused but is it really safe to use it? My machine had a RAID 1/0 system but i'm not sure what is the specific settings.

How to make sure that it's safe to format sdb and sdc? Does the available space on the gparted ensure that?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

> **How do I check whether my sdb and sdc drives is mounted? And if they are, where are they mounted?**

To find out what drives are mounted you can check `/etc/mtab`, which is a list of all devices mounted on the system. It can sometimes have various tmpfs and other things you aren't looking for mounted too, so I reccomend `cat /etc/mtab | grep /dev/sd` to get only physical devices.

As you showed in your answer df also works, if it doesn't show up in df, it's not mounted.

> **How can I mount all spare unused drives into a single directory? 
>   If not a single directory into separate directories in /media/?**

The file `/etc/fstab` contains a list of drives on the system and rules for when, how and where to mount them. when you type in `mount /dev/sda1` mount checks fstab for info on how to mount the disk. `mount: can't find /dev/sdc1 in /etc/fstab or /etc/mtab` means that mount didn't find a line in mtab for the disk, not that it failed to find the disk itself.

You can make mount not look in fstab by specifying where to mount the drive yourself, as in `mkdir /media/sdb1; mount /dev/sdb1 /media/sdb1`

If you edit fstab to add entries for your spare drives, you can make your spare drives mount at boot.

You can install pysdm to make writing entries in `/etc/fstab` easy.

> **How do I check which disk is used and which disk is still a clean slate[?]**

The best way would probably be to try to mount any partitions on it and look at the data. based on the screenshots from gparted `/dev/sdb1` and `/dev/sdc1` look to be formatted and have data on them. Gparted doesn't have anything in the "Space Used" column for unformatted drives, because you can't use space on an unformatted drive.

> **What is a GPT?**

It's a header at the beginning of a disk that describes where the different partitions on the disk begin and end, and some metadata about them. It supersedes and maintains some compatibility with an older format for this task called MBR(Master Boot Record).

Comment: I use Unraid and no command works for me. `/etc/mtab` contains only the usb flash drive. `/etc/fstab` contains nothing useful at all. And simply executing `mount` lists only mounts to `/dev/mdX` but not the correlation to `sdX`. The same is valid for `lsblk` (it lists `sdX` devices, but not correlation, too). Not sure if this related to Unraid or the underlying Slackware.

Answer (score 1):

`mount` views all currently mounted disks.
You can use `mount /dev/sdXY /mnt/DISK` to manually mount disks wher X stands for the disk number and Y is the partition number and "DISK" is the mount point. This "DISK" directory should be different for each disk and shoul exist before mounting